# Comparing two arrays and split duplicate values into separate arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var y = 0;
var a = [];
var ob = {};
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    if (new Date(rows[i].date).getTime()  === new Date(dates[y]).getTime()) {
        ob.sum = parseInt(rows[i].calls);
        ob.date = rows[i].date;
        ob.time = rows[i].time;

        a[y] = ob;
    }
    else {
        y++
    }

}
```

'rows' in an object with many many rows per date, and is containing data from several dates.
'dates' is an array with the relevant dates only.

What I am trying to achieve:
I want to match the dates and as long as there is a match

a) Create one array/object

b) Populate it with all the rows (as you see, calls and time) associated with that date.

c) Increment 'y' and do this for each matching date.

I assume that I am doing something wrong when I am trying to create the object, but please advise.

```
console.log(a[0]):


{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
1
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
2
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
3
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
4
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
5
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
6
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
7
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
8
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
9
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
10
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
11
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
12
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
13
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
14
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
15
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
16
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
17
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
18
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
19
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
20
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
21
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
22
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
23
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
24
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
25
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
26
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
27
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
28
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
29
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
30
:
{sum: 1, date: Thu Aug 31 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), time: 12}
```

'rows' is an object with thousands of rows, around hundred per day. The only thing that's unique is 'time'. I want the same thing but one object per date,

```
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 9}
1
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 9}
2
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 5}
3
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 8}
4
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 6}
5
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 3}
6
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 8}
7
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 8}
8
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 8}
9
:
row {date: Tue Aug 01 2017 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time), calls: 1, time: 9}
```

Comment: use lodash's intersection method if you please

Comment: please add the content of `rows`, error and wanted result

Comment: Some sample data would massively help

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: please use `JSON.stringify` for the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to compare two Arrays of objects and take the same objects to another object , and remove the same elements from these arrays, right?

If so  :

let's say your 2 arrays are  `var arr1 = [...] ; var arr2= [...]`

and lets say you have unique `ID` for all  objects

and you have `arr3 =[];` for pushing the repeated objects

in order to compare them both , you can use double `for loop`  like :

```
for (var i = 0; i <arr1.length ; i++){
   for (var j = 0; j <arr2.length ; i++){
      if( arr1[i].id === arr2[j].id)  {
         //Youre here if you have same object in your two arrays.
         arr3.push(arr1[i]); // we are pushing the duplicated obj to arr3
         arr1.splice(i,1); // removing the tobject from arr1
         arr2.splice(j,1); // removing the tobject from arr2
      }
   }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Hello, if I do this. I get one object per date instead. What I'd like to achieve is all the rows associated to that day per object.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  The array variable a is your array of objects; isn't that your "one object" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just speculation without any supplied error date but

```
var ob = {};
```

Needs to be inside your if block, otherwise you're just overwriting attributes of the same object. 
--EDIT.  This isn't the whole bible but it might help....

```
    var y = 0;
var a = [];
var ob = {sum:parseInt(rows[0].calls), date:rows[0].date, time:rows[0].date.getTime()};
//This was just for my intellisense
//var rows = [];
//sort rows.  This is very important.....
rows.sort(sortFn);
//Now that all rows are sorted, we just "seek" forward sum-ing up the call value of each row in 
//ob.  When we encounter two rows with different dates we can be assured there are no more rows with the previous date
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
    //var currentRow = rows[i];
    //var nextRow = rows[i + 1];
    for(var j = i + 1;j < rows.length;j++){
        if(rows[i].date.getTime() === rows[j].date.getTime()){
            ob.sum += parseInt(rows[j].calls);
        }
        else{
            //Add and then reset our object.  The below line is a cheap way to "deep copy" an object.
            //It may be overkill but it'll keep from maintaining a pointer that overrites elements of "a";
            a.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ob))); 
            ob = {sum:parseInt(rows[j].calls), date:rows[j].date, time:rows[j].getTime()};
            break;
        }
    }
}
//Custom sort function.
function sortFn(a,b){
    //You may have to fiddle with this.  If the dates resolve to date objects then
    //get rid of the new Date calls and just call getTime on them.
    var timeA = new Date(a).getTime(), timeB = new Date(b).getTime();
    if(timeA > timeB) return 1;
    if(timeA < timeB) return -1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, if I do this. I get one object per date instead. What I'd like to achieve is all the rows associated to that day per object.

Comment: Not sure I follow. The array variable a is your array of objects; isn't that your "one object" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use lodash's `_.intersectionBy` method smth like:

```
_.intersectionBy( 
  [{sum: 1, date: "today", time: 12}, {sum: 1, date: "tomorrow", time: 12}], 
  [{sum: 1, date: "today", time: 12}],  
  'date'); 

// => [{sum: 1, date: "today", time: 12}]
```

Reference docs: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy

Answer (score 0):

Update: this gave me the desired result:

```
        var y = 0;
        var x = 0;
        var arr = [];
        var ob = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) {
            if (new Date(rows[i].date).getTime()  === new Date(dates[y]).getTime() ) {
                var ob = {};
                for (var x; x < rows.length; x++) {
                    if(new Date(rows[x].date).getTime()  === new Date(dates[y]).getTime() ) {
                ob[x] = 
   {
     'sum': parseInt(rows[x].calls),
     'date': rows[x].date,
     'time': rows[x].time
   };
   arr[y] = ob;
        }
    }
}
        else {
            x = i;
            y++;
        }

    }
```

I get an array with one object for each day, containing one object per row.
My next challange though is to sort each day on 'time', individually. 
I have sorted arrays before, but can't figure out how with this structure.

```
[
  {
    "0": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 7
    },
    "1": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 8
    },
    "2": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 9
    },
    "3": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 5
    },
    "4": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 13
    },
    "5": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 10
    },
    "6": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 6
    },
    "7": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 8
    },
    "8": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 13
    },
    "9": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 8
    },
    "10": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 11
    },
    "11": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 6
    },
    "12": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 7
    },
    "13": {
      "sum": 1,
      "date": "2017-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "time": 6
    }
  }
]
```